# Linear clutching function properties

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, topological-k-theory

I'm trying to prove proposition $4.8$ of Husemöller (pay 148)

Here it is the text:

[image: husemoller pag148]

Where the only hints are:

> $[L^{n+1}(\xi),L^{n+1}(zp)] \approx [L^{n}(\xi),L^{n}(p)] \oplus [\xi,z]$
>
> $[L^{n+1}(\xi),L^{n+1}(p)] \approx [L^{n}(\xi),L^n(p)] \oplus [\xi , Id]$

**Notations:** $\xi$ is a vector bundle over $X$. $L^n(\xi)=(n+1)\xi$. With $[ \xi , f]$ i'll denote the usual clutch construction, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859302/filling-the-details-of-a-construction-via-clutching-function-of-a-vector-bundle) I found a short explanation of it. With $(L^{n+1}(\xi,p))_{\pm}$ I'll denote the usual $\pm$ splitting with the property that $L^n(\xi) = L^n(\xi,p)_+ \oplus L^n(\xi,p)_-$ **and** for a linear clutching function $L^n(q)$, the following formula holds $[L^n(\xi),L^n(p)] \approx [(L^n(\xi,p))_+,Id]\oplus [(L^n(\xi,p))_-,z]$

I tried writing down the hints and using the splitting, and I obtain at the left side of the $\approx$ the term $[(L^{n+1}(\xi,p))_-,z]$ and at the right side $[(L^{n}(\xi,p))_-,z]$. I don't know if I can do something to this pair of bundles. They are quite similar and I'm tempted to "simplify" the $n+1$ but I don't think it makes sense. So I don't know any other way to solve it. Maybe the cause is that I can't handle very well the linearization of a polynomial clutching function, but again, I don't know where to study the properties I don't know.

Thanks for every advices/hints/solutions

Comment: I think the answer is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some hints about the prop.

You have to prove two facts

**fact 1** The clutch construction preserve direct sum

**fact 2** The $\pm$ splitting is unique and preserve the direct sum

Using these facts you can easily prove your statement

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44042/proof-of-external-product-theorem-using-k-theory/864414#864414) you can find one of  my old answer with some calculation done:)

Comment: I don't get what kind of uniqueness are you using, could you please elaborate?